# Find and click hidden dropdown on Web of Science

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

You can avoid registering a web of science account by opening the link in private browsing mode or directly run my codes.

I need to grab large-scale data from the Web of Science. You can click [here](https://www.webofscience.com/wos/woscc/summary/9110e4d1-3d85-49d2-81b2-af843061855d-55cb3b26/relevance/1) to view it. I'm trying to use python selenium to solve this problem. Here are my codes

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

link: str = "https://www.webofscience.com/wos/woscc/summary/9110e4d1-3d85-49d2-81b2-af843061855d-55cb3b26/relevance/1"

def initial():
    driver: webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(driverPath))
    driver.get(link) # open website by chorme

    cookieschose = driver.find_element("id", "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")  # locate cookies setting button
    actchian = ActionChains(driver)
    actchian.move_to_element(to_element=cookieschose).click().perform()  # where the bug appeared
    time.sleep(2)    

    export = driver.find_element("class name", "mat-button-wrapper")  # find export button
    actchian.click(on_element=export).perform()  # click export button
    # excel = driver.find_element("xpath", """//*[@id="exportToExcelButton"]""") # where the same bug will appear
    # actchian.click(excel).perform()
```

The tricky thing is I got stuck on the first step. Once you go to the web page, it requires your cookies' permission and you need to click a button. I manage to locate it and store it in the variable "cookieschose". But my computer will show me "selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds"
when it execute "actchian.move_to_element(to_element=cookieschose).click().perform()"

Nothing will change after I modify "move_to_element" to "click." The more depressing thing is later I need to order computer to click "export" button and choose "excel" from a list of options. But now I even cannot sure whether my codes run correctly.

All in all, there are two questions from me:

1. how to fix the bug?
2. how can I know whether my python selenium automated codes running in right way?
3. if you are willing, please help me on finding and click "excel" in the export option list. It will appear only after you click "export". Usually, it is hidden. You can see its structure below or click the above link.
   Thank you in advance if you can help me.

The export->excel available for both users and visitors.

Here is the part of the HTML codes of the cookies page:

```
<button id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler">accept all Cookie</button>
```

The part of codes of "excel" in the option list:

```
<button mat-menu-item="" 
class="mat-focus-indicator export-option mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted"  id="exportToExcelButton" 
aria-label="Excel" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" 
aria-disabled="false"> Excel <div matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-menu-ripple"></div><!----></button>
```

Comment: why do you need `actionChains()` to click? why not simple `element.click()`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I just tried it. Now it shows me "ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (828, 564)" is this means I located in the wrong place?

Comment: I have posted an answer, please check if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try with WebDriverWait() and wait for element to be clickable.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
#click on cookie
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

#click on export button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#exportToExcelButton"))).click()
```

Import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

If above solution gives you element interactable issue. Try with js script to click as an workaround.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
#click on cookie
cookietbtn=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cookietbtn)

#click on export button
exportbutton=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#exportToExcelButton")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", exportbutton)
```

Comment: This user will not accept your answer...